# Correctly wiring batteries for solar charging

Tags: battery-charging, solar-cell

Can I charge a standard crank 12v car battery in parallel with two 6v 225ah batteries that have been wired in series using a solar charger.

Comment: Can you wire a 12V battery to two series-wired 6V batteries?  Sure.  Whether it will achieve your goal depends on what that goal is.  Please elaborate.  How that relates to solar charging is also not obvious from your question.  After now re-reading again a few times, I'm guessing you meant 'two 6V 225ah solar panels'?  I would also guess you then really meant 225mAh?  Do you expect those cells to charge a 12V car battery?

Comment: If the question is whether it's safe to wire solar panels to a battery without some kind of charge controller, current limiter, or even a diode, the answer is definitely not.

Comment: I have two 100w solar panels and a 20amp charge controller.

Comment: No, I guess it wouldn't be 6V 225ah solar panels, as that doesn't make sense either (having Ah ratings on solar panels).  So I guess I would need more detail to provide any suggestions.

Comment: Wanting to know if all of the batteries will be evenly charged to their full capacities?

Answer (score 0):

If these batteries are of the same type (all flooded lead-acid, or all AGM, or all gel-cell), and they are all relatively equal in age and usage, then you can connect them together and they will all charge.  The problem is if one of the batteries is older than the others, or has been abused, then the charging will not be equal, and all batteries may not get fully charged, or will be overcharged.

It is unlikely that this will cause dangerous problems, but if the batteries are not well-matched then you will get sub optimal charging.

If the batteries are not of the same type, then you definitely don't want to connect them together.